# get the value field of radiobutton based on Id using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a couple of radiobuttons and each radiobutton has a unique Id and a value assigned which is hidden from the front end user, my requirement is that when the user clicks on the submit button i want to get the values of the radiobuttons based on the Id of the buttons...i will pass the Id of the radio button and want to get the value of the radiobutton..

```
<input type="radio" id="t1" name="group1" value="Tpsc"><br>
<input type="radio" id="t2" name="group1" value="Empcs"> <br>
<input type="radio" id="t3" name="group1" value="Hr1">
```

i have nothing to do whether the radiobutton is checked or not, if i pass t1 then i should get value ="Tpsc"

this requirement might sound very silly , but my actual requirement is some other where i need to implement this in my Mvc3 project

Comment: `-1` This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant to your case, but if you need to pass data without showing it to the user, you should use `<input type='hidden' ... >`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function

```
 $('#t1').val()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yf2S5/)

You can crete a function like

```
function GetValue(id)    {
  return $("#"+id).val(); 
}
```

Usage

```
var value = GetValue('t1');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yf2S5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetVal(idOfControl)
{
  return $("#"+idOfControl).val(); 
}
```

and call it like

```
var thatRadioValue=GetVal("t1");
```

Here is a working sample http://jsbin.com/olANuXo/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your request, but if you want to get the value from it by ID, then you can select it with jQuery.

```
var value = $('#t1').attr('value');
```

Comment: Or you could also use the .val() function to return its value.